# Pc random reboot

Tags: power-supply, gpu, reboot

I've recently built my first desktop pc, the config is:
I7 6700
Rx 480 4gb
B150m mortar msi
8gb vengeance 3000mhz
500gb sshd firecuda 
Total power consumption 380w 
Psu: seasonic 520w with 480w on the 12v rail. 
I've been using my pc with almost any issue for 2 months and then it started reboot randomly. For example, yesterday my pc rebooted only once when I was using ms edge but two days ago it rebooted lots of times both on low and high load. My pc Passed memtest, 1h prime95 and 1h uningine. Yesterday I tried use my igpu instead of my rx 480 and the pc seems stable, it stayed on 10h whiteout rebooting.i'm sure is an hardware issue since it rebooted even in the bios or while running a Linux live cd
I don't know how to solve this problem? Can you help me?

Comment: Anything interesting in the system event logs?

Comment: Window rebooted without shutting down properly, this could be caused by system stop responding, system crashed or a power issue (or something similar, I'm not using the pc right now)

Comment: Next time you are, please [edit] and include those event log entries.

Comment: @DavidPostill The error is logged as kernel-power, event 41 and report almost the same I've wrote in the last comment

Comment: [Windows Kernel event ID 41 error "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first" in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2028504/windows-kernel-event-id-41-error-the-system-has-rebooted-without-cleanly-shutting-down-first-in-windows-8.1,-windows-8,-windows-server-2012-r2,-windows-server-2012,-windows-7,-or-windows-server-2008-r2)

Comment: [How to fix Windows 10 error Event ID 41 ‘Kernel-Power’](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/faq/id-3128570/fix-windows-error-event-kernel-power.html)

Comment: [Lots more reading here](https://www.google.com/search?q=eventid+41&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)

Comment: @DavidPostill so is a psu issue for sure? Is it normal that a "oversized"(380w consumption against a 520w psu) seasonic psu fail in two months? The strange thing is that this error seems to came out almost only in idle state and not when the power consumption become higher

Comment: I've no idea :/

Comment: @DavidPostill I've searched on internet for two weeks but I haven't found anything useful, this is why I asked here